# Get customer Email in return URL after making payment using PayPal button

Tags: paypal

How can i get customer Email in return URL after making payment using PayPal button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['tx']))
{
$tx = $_GET['tx'];


$your_pdt_identity_token = //token

$request = curl_init();

// Set request options
curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', //sandbox!!!
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array
    (
      'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
      'tx' => $tx,
      'at' => $your_pdt_identity_token,
    )),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
  // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
  // CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
));

// Execute request and get response and status code
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close connection
curl_close($request);
}
if($status == 200 AND strpos($response, 'SUCCESS') === 0)
{

$singlequantity = explode("\n",$response);

$email = $singlequantity[15];

$count = null;
$email = preg_replace('"%40"', '@', $email, -1, $count);

preg_match("/payer_email=(.*)/", $email, $email);




}
else
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">   
window.location="cancel.php"; 
</script>';

} 


?>
```

i know i shoved it in real hard right now , but this might be useful to other users attempting to do this.